# Body background image not showing

Tags: html, css

```css
body {
    background-image:url(../images/bg.jpg);
}
```

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="default.aspx.cs" Inherits="test.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <link href="style/StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>

        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I made that page as login page and made the stylesheet file in style folder. when I linked the CSS to HTML the background don't change.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take some time to follow the [Stack Overflow tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Also provide us the relevant code you wrote for your question (You can also read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either your CSS file is not in that location, or the image is not in that location. Open the browser inspector, e.g. in Google Chrome, press [F12]. This should show you the error message that either the CSS file or the image was not found.

Comment: thanks... the css file (styelsheet.css) is in the root of web site and because the login page is in the admin folder this address did not work ("style/stylesheet.css").. so how can i address image in css? when the asp page is in the "admin" folder but the image is in the root of website???

Comment: You can use an absolute path, e.g. `/admin/images/bg.jpg`, depending on the location of the image...